# Create JSON Array key dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm Having a JSON that is getting creates in `for-loop`.

Here my main requirement is to create the `Key` from a predefined variable.

Here is the code that I'm using.

```js
var rows =["Hello Trt", "Ho there", "I'm up"];
var name="Hello";
var jsonData = {};
var intentName=[];
var mainPersonel = {};
var intents = {};
intents.intentName = rows;
mainPersonel.intents=intents;
console.log(JSON.stringify(mainPersonel));
```

Looking into the other SO posts, I'm able to find on how can I replace `intents` variable, but here in my case, I want to replace `intentName` with `name` in the output.

Expected output is

```
{"intents":{"Hello":["Hello Trt","Ho there","I'm up"]}}
```

Please let me know on how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: `intents[name]=rows` should do the trick, this produced the following output: `{"intents":{"Hello":["Hello Trt","Ho there","I'm up"]}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the below code satisfies your requirement.

```js
var rows =["Hello Trt", "Ho there", "I'm up"];
var name="Hello";
var jsonData = {};
var intentName=[];
var mainPersonel = {};
var intents = {};
intents[name]= rows;
mainPersonel.intents=intents;
console.log(JSON.stringify(mainPersonel));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
intents[name]= rows;
```